# Check if txt file contains specific itemNumber in Java

Tags: java

I got a txt file called "store.txt". I need to check every line in the file too see if an item number is equal to an entered item number, and return the name you see to the right in the file.

An example from that file you see here:

```
item1234, Badesalt
item123, Salpetersyre
item12, Clorid
item1, Kulsyre
```

This is just an example. So far i almost got it, but then again , its not 100 % good enought.

my code so far:

```
// Search for item name and sends it back.
String fromFile;
String ItemName = null;
while ((fromFile = file.br.readLine()).contains(itemNumber)) {
    System.out.println("loop going");
    String[] parts = fromFile.split(",");
    ItemName = parts[1];
}
System.out.println("Itemname are: " + ItemName);
```

So, i have tried it, but it did not work very well. If i enter item number = item1234, my while loop will loop it 2x times and return item1234, Badesalt which is what i want, but i also returns item123, Salpetersyre.

So how do i make it, so i only get item1234, Badesalt back, if itemNumber is = item1234??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through loop by checking fromFile's equalness to null, not by checking if it including user entry. Because on first iteration of loop, it is checking if the first line includes user entry and if it is not, it directly skips the loop. So your code will only work correct if user entry is included at the first line. Otherwise, it will not satisfy the loop condition. So, below code should work:

```
String itemNumber = //Comes from user;
String fromFile;
String[] tokens;

while((fromFile = file.br.readLine()) != null) {

   tokens = fromFile.split(", ");

   if(tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase(itemNumber)) {

      System.out.println(tokens[1]);
      break;
   }

}
```

Comment: I try it.. give me a min

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope you understand the change in loop condition. You see, that condition will be satisfied only when the first line of text file includes user input. You would want to check every line of file instead of only the first one, don't you? :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "returns" you actually mean "prints".

This code will print the item number of all items whose name matches `requestedItemName`.

```
String fromFile;
String requestedItemName = "badesalt";

while ((fromFile = file.br.readLine()).contains(itemNumber)) {

    System.out.println("loop going");
    // Splits up string to get the name
    String[] parts = fromFile.split(",");
    if (requestedItemName.equalsIgnoreCase(parts[1])) {
        System.out.println("Item number is: " + parts[0]);
    }
}
```

Or, if you wanted to search by item number, you could do it like this:

```
String itemNumber = "item1234";
while(...) {
    ...
    if (itemNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])) {
        System.out.println("Item name is: " + parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
    //Store the lines in a Map
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split(",");
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
    in.close();

    // Search the item in the map
   if(map.get(itemNumber)!=null)
   {
   ItemName = map.get(itemNumber);
   System.out.println(ItemName);
   }
```